# How do I set the colour of brackets/braces/parentheses in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp, dot-emacs

I'd like to specify the colour of `{}`, `()` and `[]` in a custom colour theme. Is this possible?

**Update:** Here's the source. Please note the in-development status of this theme; it is unsafe for use both at the workplace and around the home.

```
;;; Color theme based on Moria for VIM.
(defun color-theme-moria ()
  "A color theme based on Moria for VIM."
  (interactive)
  (color-theme-install
   '(color-theme-moria
     ((foreground-color . "#000000") ;done
      (cursor-color . "#ffffff")
      (background-color . "#f0f0f0") ;done
      (background-mode . light)) ;done
     (default ((t (nil)))) ;done
     (underline ((t (:underline t)))) ;done
     (modeline ((t (:foreground "black" :background "#000000"))))
     (modeline-buffer-id ((t (:foreground "red" :background "#0000ff"))))
     (modeline-mousable ((t (:foreground "cyan" :background "#007080"))))
     (modeline-mousable-minor-mode ((t (:foreground "cyan" :background "#007080"))))
     (highlight ((t (:background "#d0d0d0")))) ;done
     (region ((t (:background "#c0c0c0")))) ;done
     (font-lock-builtin-face ((t (:foreground "black"))))
     (font-lock-constant-face ((t (:foreground "#ff0000")))) ;hmmm
     (font-lock-comment-face ((t (:foreground "#786000")))) ;done
     (font-lock-function-name-face ((t (:foreground "#000000" )))) ;done
     ; highlight ma brackets
     (font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("\\([\{\}\\[\]\(\)]+\\)" 1 font-lock-keyword-face prepend)))
     (font-lock-preprocessor-face ((t (:foreground "#912F11" :bold t))))
     (font-lock-keyword-face ((t (:foreground "#1f3f81" :bold t)))) ; done e.g. defun

     (font-lock-string-face ((t (:foreground "#077807")))) ;done
     (font-lock-variable-name-face ((t (:foreground "#ff0000" )))) ;hmmm
     (font-lock-warning-face ((t (:foreground "#ff0000"))))
     (highlight-changes-face ((t (:background "#ff0000"))))
     (highlight-changes-delete-face ((t (:foreground "red" :background "pink"))))
     (show-paren-match ((t (:foreground "#2e3436" :background "#73d216"))))

     (widget-field-face ((t (:foreground "pink" :background "red"))))
     (widget-inactive-face ((t (:foreground "gray"))))
     (custom-button-face ((t (:foreground "yellow" :background "dark blue"))))
     (custom-state-face ((t (:foreground "mediumaquamarine"))))
     (custom-face-tag-face ((t (:foreground "goldenrod" :underline t))))
     (custom-documentation-face ((t (:foreground "#10D010"))))
     (custom-set-face ((t (:foreground "#2020D0"))))
     )
   )
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("\\([\{\}\\[\]\(\)]+\\)" 1 font-lock-keyword-face prepend)))
```

**For parent match only:**

Evaluate the following expression or put it into your .emacs:

```
(custom-set-faces
 '(show-paren-match ((t (:background "blue"))))
 '(show-paren-mismatch ((((class color)) (:background "red" :foreground "white")))))
```

Comment: That only seems to do it when your cursor is over a paren. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Oh you wanted to colorize it from the start. Edited the answer. Try the one suggested.

Comment: I can get it to colorize just the round brackets only in the buffer where I'm editing the theme and only sometimes? If I add that to the theme and open another emacs it doesn't do anything. Strange?!

Comment: @MDCore Edited. can you try again?

Comment: Still not getting joy. I've updated the question with the full source

Answer (score 2):

You can use rainbow-delimiters mode, you can install it from MELPA in Emacs24 packages system or download rainbow-delimiters.el from:

[emacswiki-RainbowDelimiters](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RainbowDelimiters)

place rainbow-delimiters.el on your emacs load-path

write init code in your .emacs file:

```
(require 'rainbow-delimiters)

(global-rainbow-delimiters-mode)
```

Comment: This results in: `Symbol's function definition is void: global-rainbow-delimiters-mode`